# Having two types of view for one path

Tags: 7, views

I need a view for taxonomy terms that shows both any child terms as links and a table of product nodes tagged with the term, but I can only work out how to apply one or the other.

Any help appreciated!

edit for clarity: For the path taxonomy/term/%, I need to show the child terms of parent terms, or for a child term a table of all products (nodes) that are associated with that term. I have assumed it would be easiest to combine these two into one view somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it are you trying to display two different views on one page? if so have a look at panels, or you can do it manually by loading the views pragmatically in the template.
if not, please clarify.

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully be a bit clearer. I'll have a look at Panels, thanks!

Comment: I ended up using Panels to display two views, it works perfectly. Thanks again!